# Extract the value of a HTML node using VB.NET

Tags: xml, vb.net, saml, descendant

I am trying to extract a value of a HTML node using VB.NET.

This is the form:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Submit Form</title>
        <meta name="referrer" content="origin"/>
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    </head>
    <body onload="javascript:document.forms[0].submit()">
       <noscript>
            <p>
                <strong>Note:</strong> Since your browser does not support JavaScript, you must press the Resume button once to proceed.
            </p>
        </noscript>
          <form method="post" action="https://test.aspx">
             <input type="hidden" name="SAMLResponse" value="123456789"/>            
             <noscript><input type="submit" value="Resume"/></noscript>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I would like to extract

```
123456789
```

I already tryed this:

```
Dim SAMLResponse As String = CType(xmlURLDecodedXML.Descendants().Where(Function(x) x.Name.LocalName = "SAMLResponse").FirstOrDefault(), String)
```

Comment: I would get htmlagilitypack then you just do SAMLResponse =document.selectsinglenode("//input").tostring

Answer (score 0):

In your case, try with this (with assumption: the node input of SAMLResponse will not change, because the attribute position will change too) :

```
    Dim myArray() As XElement = MyXelement.Descendants().ToArray
    Dim myname As String = ""
    Dim myValue As String = ""
    For a = 1 To myArray.Count
        If myArray(a - 1).Name.ToString = "input" Then
            Try
                If myArray(a - 1).Attributes.ToArray(1).Value = "SAMLResponse" Then
                    myValue = myArray(a - 1).Attributes.ToArray(2).Value
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        End If
    Next
```

in your html:

```
<input type="hidden" name="SAMLResponse" value="123456789"/>

so

The Node Name is input
The First Attribute is Hidden
The Second Attribute is SAMLResponse
The Third Attribute is 123456789
```